# Passing An Bbject To A Class By Refrence

Tags: c#, xna

```
shotmanager = new Shotmanager(shottexture, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds, ref spaceship, enemyship);
```

Im passing spaceship with its parameters as an object to the class "shotmanager", but the problem is the parameters of spaceship is fixed and doesnt change, even though when im changing for example "position" of the ship!

here is the constructor of shotmanager:

```
    public Shotmanager(Texture2D shottexture, Rectangle Movementbounds, ref shipclass spaceship, EnemyManager enemyship)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        this.shottexture = shottexture;
        this.Movementbounds = Movementbounds;
        this.spaceship = spaceship;
        this.enemyship =  enemyship;
    }
```

Here is where I used the object "spaceship"

```
            {
                Fireshot( spaceship.position, spaceshipshotvelocity);
            }
```

I keep changing the position, but apparently the object is not sent by refrence, in other words the initial values of spaceship are sent.

Im a beginner programmer please dont banish me.

Comment: Is your `shipclass` a value-type? (that is, is the class definition written something like `public struct shipclass`?) I'm assuming you're changing the position within the `Fireshot` method, can you post your `Fireshot` method? If I had to guess, the way you're "changing the position of the ship" is you're just altering the position value passed into `Fireshot` but this is likely a copy of the coordinates; you may need to reassign the new value onto the ship itself.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.
for A) Is your ship class value type?
I declared a class shipclass for spaceship object.

B)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair


B)Can you post fireshot method? 

        private void Fireshot(Vector2 spaceshipposition, Vector2 spaceshipshotvelocity)
        {
            var shotposition = spaceshipposition;
            var shot = new Shot(shottexture, shotposition, Movementbounds);
            shots.Add(shot);
        }
C) Position is a 2d vector in Class shipclass, the problem is when I change the position of the object spaceship, the variable position that has been passed to firemanager doesnt change. I think I have to  pass it by reference.

Comment: I cant format the text in a proper way

Comment: A suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes, you're right, you're modifying a copy of the shot's position. Perhaps in addition to registering the shot, you also store the spaceship so you can update the shot when the spaceship moves. I suspect XNA also lets you position the shot relative to the spaceship (like a child object) but not sure how that's done in XNA.

Comment: The code you have posted seems fine and you dont need the 'ref'. C# .Net passes by value, BUT, it passes objects by their reference value which means that changes you make to the object are persisted. This how I know the issue is somewhere else in your code.